# Check if customer appears mulitple times in table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that gets updated everyday with an insert-time. Now I want to check if a customer appears in both insert-times or only in one of them and mark them accordingly.

```
insert-time     Customer           customer-appereance
2019-08-17      Customer01           each-insert-time
2019-08-18      Customer01           each-insert-time
2019-08-17      Customer02           first-list
2019-08-17      Customer03           each-insert-time
2019-08-18      Customer03           each-insert-time
2019-08-17      Customer04           first-list
2019-08-18      Customer05           last-list
```

My database looks like this:

```
insert-time    customer
2019-08-17     Customer01
2019-08-17     Customer02
2019-08-17     Customer03
2019-08-17     Customer04
2019-08-18     Customer01
2019-08-18     Customer03
2019-08-18     Customer05
```

The query I tried is this:

```
SELECT insert_time, customer,
(CASE WHEN MIN(insert_time) over (PARTITION by customer) = MAX(insert_time) over (PARTITION by customer)
THEN 'first-list' ELSE 'last-list' END) AS customer-appereance
FROM customers
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Somehow it does not work. I am alos wondering how I can put the third cirtiera "each-insert-time" into the CASE statement?

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: MySQL version is MariaDB 10.3

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (SELECT customer, MIN(`insert-time`) mindate, MAX(`insert-time`) maxdate
         FROM customers
         GROUP BY customer),
cte2 AS (SELECT MIN(`insert-time`) mindate, MAX(`insert-time`) maxdate
         FROM customers)
SELECT customers.`insert-time`,
       customers.customer,
       CASE WHEN cte1.mindate = cte2.maxdate THEN 'last-list'
            WHEN cte2.mindate = cte1.maxdate THEN 'first-list'
            ELSE 'each-insert-time'
            END `customer-appereance`
FROM customers
JOIN cte1 USING (customer)
CROSS JOIN cte2
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

or

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN MIN(`insert-time`) OVER (PARTITION BY customer) = MAX(`insert-time`) OVER ()
            THEN 'last-list'
            WHEN MAX(`insert-time`) OVER (PARTITION BY customer) = MIN(`insert-time`) OVER ()
            THEN 'first-list'
            ELSE 'each-insert-time'
            END `customer-appereance`
FROM customers
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=31acf7cdd2dae17593503bea9bb033e9)

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=dffef784b8dd441f3b734318740b4225)